How to make the camera to follow the model from a third-person perspective
I’m working on a Three.js project where I need a third-person camera setup that follows a 3D model as it moves around the scene. I have a basic implementation with animations and controls, but I’m struggling to make the camera follow the model properly. Here’s a summary of what I’m trying to achieve and the current issues I'm facing:
Problem Summary:
I want the camera to follow the model from a third-person perspective. Specifically, as the model moves in different directions (forward, backward, left, right), the camera should always follow the model while maintaining a fixed distance and orientation.
Current Implementation:
<script setup>
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { OrbitControls } from 'three/addons/controls/OrbitControls.js';
import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';
import { onMounted, ref } from 'vue';

const container3D = ref(null);

onMounted(() => {
    let object, mixer, walkAction, shutdownAction, CycleBackAction, jumpAction;
    const scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xf0f0f0);
    const cameraOffset = new THREE.Vector3(0, 30, -50); 
    const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 5000);

    scene.add(camera);

    const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    container3D.value.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    const loader = new GLTFLoader();
    loader.load(
        '/medium_mech_striker/scene.gltf',
        (gltf) => {
            object = gltf.scene;
            object.scale.set(10, 10, 10);
            object.position.y = -200;
            object.rotateY(Math.PI);
            object.frustumCulled = false;
            scene.add(object);

            // Setup animations
            mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer(object);
            gltf.animations.forEach((clip) => {
                if (clip.name === 'a5WalkCycle') {
                    walkAction = mixer.clipAction(clip);
                    walkAction.setEffectiveTimeScale(1); // Adjust this value to control the speed of the walk animation
                } else if (clip.name === 'a1ShutdownPose') {
                    shutdownAction = mixer.clipAction(clip);
                } else if (clip.name === 'a6WalkCycleBack') {
                    CycleBackAction = mixer.clipAction(clip);
                } else if (clip.name === 'a8Jump') {
                    jumpAction = mixer.clipAction(clip);
                }
            });

            // Start with shutdown animation
            if (shutdownAction) {
                shutdownAction.play();
            }
        },
        undefined,
        (error) => {
            console.error('An error happened while loading the GLTF model:', error);
        }
    );

    // Create plane mesh
    const planeGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(10000, 10000);
    planeGeometry.rotateX(-Math.PI / 2);
    const planeMaterial = new THREE.ShadowMaterial({ color: 0x000000, opacity: 0.2 });

    const plane = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeometry, planeMaterial);
    plane.receiveShadow = true;
    scene.add(plane);

    const GridHelper = new THREE.GridHelper(2000, 100);
    GridHelper.position.y = -199;
    GridHelper.material.opacity = 0.25;
    GridHelper.material.transparent = true;
    scene.add(GridHelper);

    // Light
    scene.add(new THREE.AmbientLight(0xf0f0f0, 3));
    const light = new THREE.SpotLight(0xffffff, 4.5);
    light.position.set(0, 1500, 200);
    light.angle = Math.PI * 0.2;
    light.decay = 0;
    light.castShadow = true;
    light.shadow.camera.near = 200;
    light.shadow.camera.far = 2000;
    light.shadow.bias = -0.000222;
    light.shadow.mapSize.width = 1024;
    light.shadow.mapSize.height = 1024;
    scene.add(light);

    // Orbit controls
    const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
    controls.enableDamping = true;
    controls.dampingFactor = 0.25;
    controls.screenSpacePanning = false;

    // Handle keyboard input
    const keys = {};
    window.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
        keys[event.key] = true;
    });
    window.addEventListener('keyup', (event) => {
        keys[event.key] = false;
    });

    // Animation function
    function animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);

        // Update mixer if defined
        if (mixer) {
            mixer.update(0.03); // Adjust this value to control the overall animation update speed
        }

        // Handle animations
        if (object) {
            if (keys['w']) {
                if (shutdownAction && shutdownAction.isRunning()) {
                    shutdownAction.stop();
                }
                if (walkAction && !walkAction.isRunning()) {
                    walkAction.play();
                }

                if (keys['d']) {
                    object.rotation.y += 0.05;
                } else if (keys['a']) {
                    object.rotation.y -= 0.05;
                } else if (keys[' ']) {
                    if (!jumpAction.isRunning()) jumpAction.play();
                } else {
                    if (jumpAction.isRunning()) jumpAction.stop();
                }

                const direction = new THREE.Vector3();
                object.getWorldDirection(direction);
                object.position.addScaledVector(direction, 1);
            } else if (keys['s']) {
                if (walkAction && walkAction.isRunning()) {
                    walkAction.stop();
                }

                if (CycleBackAction && !CycleBackAction.isRunning()) {
                    CycleBackAction.play();
                }

                const direction = new THREE.Vector3();
                object.getWorldDirection(direction);
                object.position.addScaledVector(direction, -1);
            } else {
                if (walkAction && walkAction.isRunning()) {
                    walkAction.stop();
                }
                if (shutdownAction && !shutdownAction.isRunning()) {
                    shutdownAction.play();
                }
                if (CycleBackAction && CycleBackAction.isRunning()) {
                    CycleBackAction.stop();
                }
            }
        }
        // Update camera position to follow the object
        const objectPosition = new THREE.Vector3();
        object.getWorldPosition(objectPosition);

        // Calculate camera position based on object position and offset
        const offset = cameraOffset.clone();
        offset.applyMatrix4(object.matrixWorld);
        camera.position.copy(objectPosition).add(offset);

        // Ensure camera always faces the object
        camera.lookAt(objectPosition);

        controls.update();
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    }

    // Start animation
    animate();

    // Adjust camera and renderer size when window is resized
    window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
        camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
        camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    });
});
</script>

Issue:
The camera currently doesn’t follow the model’s movements. The camera remains static and doesn’t adjust its position or orientation based on the model’s position or rotation.
What I’ve Tried:
I have set up the camera and renderer properly.
I’ve implemented animation controls for moving and rotating the model.
I’ve used OrbitControls to manage the camera view.
Questions:
How can I modify the camera setup so that it follows the model from a third-person perspective?
What changes are needed in the code to ensure that the camera maintains a fixed distance from the model while it moves around?
Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

It doesn't look like you've tried anything, there is no code here related to attempting to make a third person follow camera. I would start with searching for your question first, and trying to implement one of the hundreds of search results, and asking a more focused question if you have a problem.

owh sorry, ill update my code.

@AndyRay, i have updating my code, maybe u can review my code,
idk whats going on, but camera desent follow the object

Implementing a 3rd person camera is complex, but as a start, maybe try implementing this in 3D: https://lazybrush.dulnan.net/ - together with a simple LookAt, it should give you at least a starting point.

yah i tried many times , and i did it, yeay...
first thing we have to know is :
...
 goal = new THREE.Object3D();
  follow = new THREE.Object3D();
  follow.position.z = -coronaSafetyDistance;
...
      object.add(follow); // follow as a child of object
      goal.add(camera);
      scene.add(object);
...
      const objectPosition = new THREE.Vector3(); // create new vector3
      object.getWorldPosition(objectPosition); // get position and copy it to objectPosition

      const offset = new THREE.Vector3(0, 200, -300); // create offset from camera to object
      const goalPosition = objectPosition.clone().add(offset); // add dynamic position from objectpostion + offset
      camera.position.lerp(goalPosition, 0.05); // setup camera from our calculate
      camera.lookAt(objectPosition);


full code :
<script setup>
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { OrbitControls } from 'three/addons/controls/OrbitControls.js';
import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';
import { onMounted, ref } from 'vue';

const container3D = ref(null);

onMounted(() => {
  let object, mixer, walkAction, shutdownAction, CycleBackAction, jumpAction;
  let goal, follow;
  let coronaSafetyDistance = 0.3;

  const scene = new THREE.Scene();
  scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xf0f0f0);

  const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
  camera.position.set(0, 30, -300);
  scene.add(camera);

  const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  container3D.value.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  goal = new THREE.Object3D();
  follow = new THREE.Object3D();
  follow.position.z = -coronaSafetyDistance;

  const loader = new GLTFLoader();
  loader.load(
    '/medium_mech_striker/scene.gltf',
    (gltf) => {
      object = gltf.scene;
      object.scale.set(10, 10, 10);
      object.position.y = -200;
      object.frustumCulled = false;
      object.add(follow);
      goal.add(camera);
      scene.add(object);

      // Setup animations
      mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer(object);
      gltf.animations.forEach((clip) => {
        if (clip.name === 'a5WalkCycle') {
          walkAction = mixer.clipAction(clip);
          walkAction.setEffectiveTimeScale(1);
        } else if (clip.name === 'a1ShutdownPose') {
          shutdownAction = mixer.clipAction(clip);
        } else if (clip.name === 'a6WalkCycleBack') {
          CycleBackAction = mixer.clipAction(clip);
        } else if (clip.name === 'a8Jump') {
          jumpAction = mixer.clipAction(clip);
        }
      });

      // Start with shutdown animation
      if (shutdownAction) {
        shutdownAction.play();
      }
    },
    undefined,
    (error) => {
      console.error('An error happened while loading the GLTF model:', error);
    }
  );

  // Create plane mesh
  const planeGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(10000, 10000);
  planeGeometry.rotateX(-Math.PI / 2);
  const planeMaterial = new THREE.ShadowMaterial({ color: 0x000000, opacity: 0.2 });

  const plane = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeometry, planeMaterial);
  plane.receiveShadow = true;
  scene.add(plane);

  const gridHelper = new THREE.GridHelper(2000, 100);
  gridHelper.position.y = -199;
  gridHelper.material.opacity = 0.25;
  gridHelper.material.transparent = true;
  scene.add(gridHelper);

  // Axes helper
  const axesHelper = new THREE.AxesHelper(100);
  scene.add(axesHelper);

  // Light
  scene.add(new THREE.AmbientLight(0xf0f0f0, 3));
  const light = new THREE.SpotLight(0xffffff, 4.5);
  light.position.set(0, 1500, 200);
  light.angle = Math.PI * 0.2;
  light.decay = 0;
  light.castShadow = true;
  light.shadow.camera.near = 200;
  light.shadow.camera.far = 2000;
  light.shadow.bias = -0.000222;
  light.shadow.mapSize.width = 1024;
  light.shadow.mapSize.height = 1024;
  scene.add(light);

  // Orbit controls
  const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
  controls.enableDamping = true;
  controls.dampingFactor = 0.25;
  controls.screenSpacePanning = false;

  // Handle keyboard input
  const keys = {};
  window.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
    keys[event.key] = true;
  });
  window.addEventListener('keyup', (event) => {
    keys[event.key] = false;
  });

  // Animation function
  function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);

    // Update mixer if defined
    if (mixer) {
      mixer.update(0.03);
    }

    // Handle animations
    if (object) {
      const direction = new THREE.Vector3();
      object.getWorldDirection(direction);

      if (keys['w']) {
        if (shutdownAction && shutdownAction.isRunning()) {
          shutdownAction.stop();
        }
        if (walkAction && !walkAction.isRunning()) {
          walkAction.play();
        }
        if (keys['d']) {
          object.rotation.y -= 0.05;
        } else if (keys['a']) {
          object.rotation.y += 0.05;
        } else if (keys[' ']) {
          if (!jumpAction.isRunning()) jumpAction.play();
        } else {
          if (jumpAction.isRunning()) jumpAction.stop();
        }
        object.position.addScaledVector(direction, 1);
      } else if (keys['s']) {
        if (walkAction && walkAction.isRunning()) {
          walkAction.stop();
        }
        if (CycleBackAction && !CycleBackAction.isRunning()) {
          CycleBackAction.play();
        }
        object.position.addScaledVector(direction, -1);
      } else {
        if (walkAction && walkAction.isRunning()) {
          walkAction.stop();
        }
        if (shutdownAction && !shutdownAction.isRunning()) {
          shutdownAction.play();
        }
        if (CycleBackAction && CycleBackAction.isRunning()) {
          CycleBackAction.stop();
        }
      }

      const objectPosition = new THREE.Vector3();
      object.getWorldPosition(objectPosition);

      const offset = new THREE.Vector3(0, 30, -300);
      const goalPosition = objectPosition.clone().add(offset);
      camera.position.lerp(goalPosition, 0.05);
      camera.lookAt(objectPosition);
    }

    controls.update();
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
  }

  // Start animation
  animate();

  // Adjust camera and renderer size when window is resized
  window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  });
});
</script>


@DarkBee yah thx for ur suggestion, i'll.. thanks
